# Detect the landscape orientation left or right

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, orientation

My app supports portrait and  landscape -> Both left and right. I am able to detect if its landscape. But not able to detect left or right. Here is my code

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
// Do some task 
}
```

When user rotates the device i need to detect whether the user rotated to landscape left or landscape right !

Same way inside my above condition I need to check whether its left or right side. How can I detect that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft {


    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {

    } else {
        //not landscape left or right
    }
```

EDIT --------

based on your comments you are looking for interface orientation instead of device orientation.

```
override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    var text=""
    switch UIDevice.current.orientation{
    case .portrait:
        text="Portrait"
    case .portraitUpsideDown:
        text="PortraitUpsideDown"
    case .landscapeLeft:
        text="LandscapeLeft"
    case .landscapeRight:
        text="LandscapeRight"
    default:
        text="Another"
    }
    NSLog("You have moved: \(text)")        
}
```

the code above detects interface orientation... 
note how the switch statement still uses UIDeviceOrientation

Below is another method that you may want to use

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("landscape")
    } else {
        print("portrait")
    }
}
```

Note again that UIDevice Orientation is still used...

Below is a very different but effective approach.

```
struct DeviceInfo {
struct Orientation {
    // indicate current device is in the LandScape orientation
    static var isLandscape: Bool {
        get {
            return UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation
                ? UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
                : UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
        }
    }
    // indicate current device is in the Portrait orientation
    static var isPortrait: Bool {
        get {
            return UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation
                ? UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait
                : UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isPortrait
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: instead of device orientation, can we able to get screen orientation (UIInterfaceOrientation) ?. To detect if its right or left ?

Comment: @britainchare is that not the same thing ? if the screen (top) is on the left side, that is equal to uidevice orientation - landscape left - if the screen (top) is on the right side , that is the same thing as screen orientation or uidevice orientation - landscape right

Comment: no both are different. Say for one particular vc i am locking my uiinterfaceOrientation to portrait when i rotate my device to landscape. My vc will be in portrait, but my device orientation will be landscape

Comment: @britainchare then what is your goal by detecting left or right landscape orientation if you are locking your VC to portrait on device orientation change ? Please edit your question to clarify... based on your current question the answer provided will detect when the user orients his/her device left or right... please clarify

Comment: he is asking about landscape left and right and you answer other things there too ... its confusing..

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this for now:

```
public extension UIScreen { 
    public class var isLandscapeLeft: Bool { UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeLeft }
    public class var isLandscapeRight: Bool { UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == .landscapeRight }
}
```

It's as extension to UIScreen just for convenience so its easy to find..
Also to detect when app actually rotates from left to right when I have just landscape enabled, I had to use AppDelegate's function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarOrientation oldStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) { ... }
```

For whatever reason nothing else get's triggered.

Looks like also, you have to use `UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation` when checking from didChangeStatusBarOrientation instead of `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.interfaceOrientation` I used for other situations.